# RJ45 termination in fast ethernet

Tags: ethernet, termination, rj45

I am working with fast Ethernet. My question is that we are using only two pairs in 100 Mbps.

How will I terminate pin 4 and 5 and pin 7 and 8?

Can I separately terminate magnetic center tap with a 75 Ω resistor and capacitor and RJ45 pins with a 75 Ω resistor and capacitor?

Or do I need to terminate magnetic center tap and RJ45 pins (4, 5 & 7, 8) together with a 75 Ω resistor for each pin and one capacitor?
What are the pro and cons of both termination styles?

Comment: See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244559/different-recommendations-for-ethernet-front-end-terminaton?rq=1

Comment: Manish Synergy - Hi, You posted 2 "answers" using the entry box at the bottom of the page labeled "Your Answer". However they were not answers and have been deleted. You were asking some kind of clarification question, but they were unclear what you were referring to, so I could not convert them into a useful comment :( Please write clear *comments* requesting clarification. (a) Stack Exchange is different from typical forums, so please read the [tour] and the [help] for the main site rules. (b) There is also an [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931).

Comment: (cont'd) (c) [This article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) explains about comments and how to use them. (d) You *must not* add new information or ask clarification questions as an *answer* here on SE. It breaks the whole Q&A approach and may cause future problems for you, when the "non-answers" get deleted. Perhaps you wanted to include an image in a comment? If so, the technique explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) should be used. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image and is then discarded.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [10/100Base-T magnetics datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Pulse%20PDFs/10_100BASE-T%20Single%20Port%20SMD%20Magnetics_Rev2008.pdf), each unused pair should be connected together and connected to ground with 75R through a 1000pF cap. There is no reason to connect these pairs to magnetics as these magnetics typically only support two pairs.

Diagram from datasheet:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Just don't**

You don't need to terminate them. In fact there plenty of fast ethernet devices out there with only 4 gold fingers in the RJ45 socket.

If you need to use them for POE that's a different matter.